# VBA to copy between workbooks without multiple selection error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that allows me to copy information from one workbook into another without the formatting,  I have written some code but always errors on the paste with "run time error 1004" cannot be used on multiple selections.  can anyone see where the error is?

I've looked around for the error but the problems all seem to be more complex copying then I am looking at doing

```
Sub panacea()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("Q:\Radiology\Administration\Data\CT Distribution\Infinity List\salvage.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("h:\Deputy\testing folder\Streamlined Infinity\test.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("infinity list")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("infinity list")

ws1.Range("C10:L12").Copy: ws2.Range("C11:L13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

wb1.Close
wb2.Close

End Sub
```

run time error 1004" cannot be used on multiple selections occurs at the moment of pasting

Comment: Are any merged cells in range of source or range of destiny?

Comment: they shouldn't be, I tried altering the range to a single cell to test that and it still produced the same error

Comment: *they shouldn't be,* can you check it? I've tried your code and it works for me perfectly.

Comment: They weren't merged cells but I have a separate macro that extracts the "salvage data", that had actually grouped the sheets, this is what was causing the issues, thank you though